# How to keep the popup menu of a JComboBox open on populating it?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, applet, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox on my Panel. One of the popup menu items is 'More' and when I click that I fetch more menu items and add them to the existing list. After this, I wish to keep the popup menu open so that the user realizes that more items have been fetched however, the popup closes. The event handler code I am using is as follows

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == myCombo) {
            JComboBox selectedBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            String item = (String) selectedBox.getSelectedItem();
            if (item.toLowerCase().equals("more")) {
                fetchItems(selectedBox);
            }
            selectedBox.showPopup();
            selectedBox.setPopupVisible(true);
        }
    }



private void fetchItems(JComboBox box)
    {
        box.removeAllItems();
        /* code to fetch items and store them in the Set<String> items */
        for (String s : items) {
            box.addItem(s);
        }
    }
```

I do not understand why the showPopup() and setPopupVisible() methods are not functioning as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add the following line in the fetchItems method

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

    public void run()
    {

       box.showPopup();
    }
```

}

If u call selectedBox.showPopup(); inside invokelater also it will work.

Comment: Thanks .. it worked. I had to create a new inner class implementing the Runnable interface and passed the JComboBox instance to the constructor of the inner class because the box object in the run() would be out of scope within the fetchItems() function.

Comment: @Stormshadow: no you didn't need to create an inner class; a much simpler solution is to declare box to be final: private void fetchItems(final JComboBox box). Then the code in this answer will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

overwrite the JCombobox setPopupVisible metod

```
public void setPopupVisible(boolean v) {
    if(v)
        super.setPopupVisible(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox(){
@Override
public void setPopupVisible(boolean v) {
    super.setPopupVisible(true); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

};

Answer (score 1):

I found some simple solution to always keep popup open. It may be useful with some custom JComboBox'es, like the one I have in my project, but is a little hacky.

```java
public class MyComboBox extends JComboBox
{
    boolean keep_open_flag = false; //when that flag ==true, popup will stay open

    public MyComboBox(){
        keep_open_flag = true; //set that flag where you need
        setRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer()); //our spesial render
    }

    class MyComboBoxRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, 
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

            if (index == -1){ //if popup hidden
                if (keep_open_flag) showPopup(); //show it again
            }
        }
    }
}
```